# Movie about Mulan

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember having a DVD in the early 2000's that told a version of Mulan's story. It had to be very small studio since I can't find any mention of it on the internet. The animation was also kind of crude.

The plot involved a dragon who had to melt the snow from the mountains for people being able to water their fields. For some reason this hadn't happen for a while causing a drought and poverty. In middle of all this some evil general began a rebellion that Mulan had to encounter.

The story involved a magical medallion that turns into different animals, both monkey and a panda sidekick and some kind of test of different elements.

If I remember correctly she eventually found out that the dragon had failed to melt the snow because he was being drugged with opium by the bad guys. Very kid friendly :D

Comment: The thing about the dragon drugged on opium seems an obvious reference to the Opium Wars. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opium_Wars

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is likely the 1998 [*The Legend of Mulan*](https://trove.nla.gov.au/work/32692135?versionId=39866454).

[image: A cover of *The Legend of Mulan*]
[image: Another cover, more cartoony]
[image: Yet another cover of *The Legend of Mulan*]

> War breaks out in China as a result of a long and disastrous draught [sic]. Mulan, daughter of a famous milllitary [sic] hero, dresses as a varrier [sic] to take the place of her father. After 12 long years, Mulan, now a leader, is captured by the enemy and taken to the dungeons. Mulan, after escaping challenges the four elements of nature so as to awaken the dragon that can melt the snow, end the drought and return peace to her people. The legend of Mulan will entice and enthrall people of all ages as it has for hundres [sic] of years.

[The IMDB summary](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0180798/) mentions the medallion and the magical animal friends

> A Chinese girl must become a warrior to fight a war and to save her village by convincing a dragon to melt the snows. She must overcome the trials of the four elements, with the help of a medallion and some magical friends.

I think this may be the corresponding trailer:

Found with a search for *film mulan dragon melt snow -disney*

Comment: Fascinating, a small Australian film, it came out at the same time as the Disney Mulan.

Comment: Yeah, it was probably an attempt to cash in on Disney's publicity as a Mockbuster.

Comment: "mockbuster" good one  !   :)

Comment: What's a "varrier"?

Comment: ^_^ Obviously, supposed to be "warrior". I'll add a "sic".

Comment: @Fattie [Mockbuster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockbuster)

Comment: Wow, that’s [sic]!

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Wasn't obvious to me. I thought it meant something like "cross dresser" (as a strange alteration of "vary")! But maybe I'm just more prone to misinterpretation than others. =)

Comment: If she were a farrier, that's make sense too. Someone had to shoe those horses...

Comment: That  description seems correct, but the youtube link and the image are not the movie I am looking for. It seems that there is another movie called "The Legend of Mulan".

Comment: @RumRums: I will pull the video. The image is from IMDB and correlates with the summary. They do have some alternate covers. I'll add those.

Comment: I am still a bit confused :D That last trailer is the movie I was looking for, but none of those images look anything like that. Were there that many movies with a same name. Even found the entire movie in danish :D https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBgkPyYM-Zw Feel free to edit the response.